# Why does the Garbage Collector runs without reaching max heap limit?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm developing an App for real time purposes. To solve a non-linear optimization problem I've integrated  the Java solver jcobyla (https://github.com/cureos/jcobyla). Every time the solver runs, the Garbage Collector is doing a lot of work with a significant runtime:

```
02-09 12:58:16.822: V/onCreate(7061): maxMemory:512524288k

02-09 13:04:23.127: D/dalvikvm(7061): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10314K, 40% free 17304K/28544K, paused 16ms, total 16ms   

02-09 13:04:23.177: D/dalvikvm(7061): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3437K, 34% free 17304K/26196K, paused 11ms, total 11ms

02-09 13:04:23.222: D/dalvikvm(7061): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3437K, 34% free 17304K/26196K, paused 10ms, total 10ms

02-09 13:04:23.322: D/dalvikvm(7061): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10304K, 33% free 17303K/25452K, paused 18ms, total 18ms

>02-09 13:04:23.367: D/dalvikvm(7061): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3437K, 33% free 17303K/25452K, paused 11ms, total 11ms

02-09 13:04:23.417: D/dalvikvm(7061): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3437K, 33% free 17303K/25452K, paused 12ms, total 12ms

02-09 13:04:23.522: D/dalvikvm(7061): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10304K, 40% free 17304K/28540K, paused 16ms, total 17ms

02-09 13:04:23.567: D/dalvikvm(7061): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3437K, 34% free 17304K/26196K, paused 11ms, total 11ms

02-09 13:04:23.612: D/dalvikvm(7061): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3437K, 34% free 17304K/26196K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
```

I tryed a lot of things to prevent GC from running. In the belief the solver reaches the max heap limit of the app I use `android:largeHeap="true"`. Running the solver in a seperate process didn't fix it neither.

As you see in the LogTag above, the max heap limit of the app is about 512MB wich is more than enough for jcobyla (needs about 300MB). GC tells me after running there are 34% free of 24.85 MB. The total RAM usage of the app while running jcobyla is about 20 MB.

Why does the limit GC shows differ from the max heap limit of the app?

How to increase the possible memory usage for the solver?

How can I prevent GC from running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every time the solver runs the Garbage Collector is doing a lot of work with a significant runtime

`GC_FOR_ALLOC` means that your request to allocate memory could not be fulfilled without a round of GC and, possibly, expanding the heap.

> wich is more than enough for jcobyla (needs about 300MB)

I have no idea how you have determined that, particularly for Android. Moreover, your own analysis claims that this is not the case, as otherwise your heap would have grown to at least 300MB, and it has not done so.

> Why does the limit GC shows differ from the max heap limit of the app?

Because the heap has not grown to the limit. The objective is to minimize the system RAM footprint of the process. The bigger the process gets, the more Android has to terminate other processes to get everything to fit in system RAM. This harms the user experience, for things like multitasking.

> How to increase the possible memory usage for the solver?

According to your analysis, you do not need to increase the possible memory usage for the solver.

> How can I prevent GC from running?

Stop using a programming language that utilizes GC, or stop programming for Android and switch to some desktop OS.

Your app is one among many for Android, and it is one among many on any given Android device. Android devices can have very little system RAM -- Android One devices, for example, may have as little as 512MB of RAM. That's for the OS and for all running app processes, not just for you. Android, particularly Dalvik/ART, is architected around a cooperative model, where each process tries to minimize its memory consumption.

But:

- if you write your app in C/C++ using the NDK, not only is there no GC, but you have no heap limits, other than the net effect of users thinking that your app is harmful to their device due to the amount of system RAM it uses
- if you write your app for another OS, you will be subject to that OS's memory-management policies, and a desktop OS is more likely to allow you to use system RAM more aggressively

Comment: @canScan, in addition, Dalvik does not use a moving garbage collector, so even if you have the requisite free space to allocate an object, there might not be enough contiguous free space, requiring a GC_FOR_ALLOC.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers. @CommonsWare, the memory usage  was measured running jcobyla on a desktop computer. It seems NDK is the only way to reach the performance I need.

Comment: @canScan: "the memory usage was measured running jcobyla on a desktop computer" -- note that the memory usage will not be identical, as the runtimes are different. As Tanis.7x notes, [Dalvik does not have a compacting (or moving) garbage collector](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/16/art-garbage-collection.html), and so you can fragment your heap easier. A plain Java library often is not optimized to minimize memory consumption the way an Android app needs (e.g., recycling existing objects rather than relying upon GC and fresh allocations).